# How do i reset the timer to start from 00:00:00 each time i run my program over again?

Tags: java, android

I added to MainActvitiy.java

```
private Button startButton;
private Button pauseButton;
private TextView timerValue;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;
```

Then in the onCreate i added:
And did that the timer will start automatic when i run the program without the need to click the start button i want the timer to start right when i run my program.

```
customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,0);

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

            }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

            }
        });
```

Then the method updateTimerThread:

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = 0L;//SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };
```

In this method i did:

```
timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
```

But it didn't change much.
what i want to do is each time i run my program from the beginning the timer will start from 00:00:00

EDIT
In the on activity i did now this:

```
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,0);
    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

        }
    });

    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

        }
    });
```

In the upadteTimerThread i didn't change:

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };
```

Still when running the program the timer is not starting from 00:00:00 but i see on the minutes a long number also in second like it's continuing not starting over like reseted.

Comment: `timeInMilliseconds = 0L;` is overwritten by the next line `timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;`

Comment: Right i tried already without the second line but it didn't work well.

Comment: Not that it matters, but use [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) instead of `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`. --- Well, it might matter, depending on how sleep mode should be handled.

Comment: Not that it matters, but combine your `format` calls: `String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", mins, secs, milliseconds)`

Comment: You need to set `startTime` before the first call to `postDelayed`

Comment: Where should i make the changes ? I changed it to System.currentTimeMillis() and then before the onCreate i did startTime = 0L; but still the timer start with a very long numer on the left on the minutes and what i wanted to do is that it will always start from 00:00:00 when running the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `startButton` `onClick` method, you have:

```
startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
```

But at the top, you only have:

```
customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread,0);
```

Since `updateTimerThread` uses the `startTime` value, you'd very likely want to initialize it the same way at the top.

Comment: Andreas i edited my question added what i did now. Still when running the program the timer is not starting from 00:00:00 but i see on the minutes a long number also in second like it's continuing not starting over like reseted.

Comment: @ShimritHadadi You initialize using `uptimeMillis`, but the thread uses `currentTimeMillis`. They are *not* the same, or in any way comparable. --- Unrelated: Why are `timeInMilliseconds` and `updatedTime` declared as fields, and not just local variables?

Answer (score 0):

The key to resetting the timer back to zero is in the `updatedTime` variable. This is what determines where the timer starts when you press the Start button.

There's no need to reinitialize the startTime variable since `startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();` already properly sets the startTime back to 0. Remember that `startTime` is relative to what's currently showing on the timer. That's why the timer starts off where you paused it and doesn't skip the seconds for when the timer was paused.

Set the `timeSwapBuff` back to `0L` in the `onClick` event for the Start Button. This resets the time buffer to 0. That then gets added back to the startTime (also 0) and forces the timer to start over completely.

Try:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
}
```